# RoboEarth installation using rosinstall

Tags: ros, python, roboearth, pip, rosinstall

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hi,

I'm trying to install RoboEarth on my Ubuntu 10.10 and I'm following the steps at [the wiki page](http://www.ros.org/wiki/roboearth). Somewhere along the line, I have to use the command `rosinstall`, but it doesn't work. When I try `sudo apt-get install python-rosinstall` , I get the following error:

```
E: Unable to locate package python-rosinstall.
```

If I try the command `sudo pip install -U rosinstall`, I get the message:

```
sudo: pip:command not found.
```

What should I do?

I'm a beginner, so any help is welcome! Thanks!

**EDIT:** After michikarg's help, I was able to run rosinstall but I'm still having problems with the installation process. Some of the dependencies were not found, even some that are already installed such as `libqt4-dev`.

Here is the log message (by the way, I'm using ROS Electric):

> This code block was moved to the following github gist:
> https://gist.github.com/answers-se-migration-openrobotics/3464675f5b7787e554a4e6cd01eda785

```
asimo@asimo:~/ros/stacks/roboearth$ rosdep install roboearth
Failed to find rosdep libqt4-dev for package re_object_detector_gui on OS:ubuntu version:maverick
rosdep install ERROR:
failed to install libqt4-dev</pre>
<pre>
asimo@asimo:~/ros/stacks/roboearth$ sudo apt-get install libqt4-dev
[sudo] password for asimo: 
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
libqt4-dev is already the newest version.
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 4 not upgraded.
```

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/49318/roboearth-installation-using-rosinstall/) by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on ROS Answers with karma: 73 on 2012-11-28

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Electric is not officially supported. If you really can't update to Fuerte, try Revision r2047:

```
roscd roboearth
svn up -r2047
```

---

Originally posted by [ddimarco](https://answers.ros.org/users/1073/ddimarco/) with karma: 916 on 2012-11-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 5

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2013-01-15**:
I have updated to Fuerte and things are going well now! Thank you ddimarco!

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I'm not sure but maybe there are no debian packages of python-rosinstall for Ubuntu 10.10 and Electric. I guess you are using ROS Electric?

As you already found out, you can use pip for installation as well. But therefore you will first have to install pip itself. You can do so by:

```
sudo apt-get install python-pip
```

A general note: You should use tags for all of your questions on ros answers so the right people get noticed and you will receive an answer faster.

---

Originally posted by [michikarg](https://answers.ros.org/users/1314/michikarg/) with karma: 2108 on 2012-11-28

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Mendelson](https://answers.ros.org/users/3146/mendelson/) on 2012-11-29**:
Thanks, that helped me get pip running... I was trying "sudo apt-get install pip"!